# Solving the trigonometric equation $4 \sin x =\sqrt{3} \csc x + 2 - 2\sqrt{3} $

Tags: trigonometry

I am asked the following question (**non-calculator**):

> Solve for $0 \leq x \leq 2 \pi$
>
> $$4 \sin x =\sqrt{3} \csc x + 2 - 2\sqrt{3} $$
>   **Answer:** $x = \frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{5 \pi}{6}, \frac{4\pi}{3}, \frac{5\pi}{3}$

My solution consists on multiplying both sides by $\sin x$ but I get stuck on a quadratic equation:

[image]

How can I proceed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
4\sin x &=\sqrt3\csc x+2-2\sqrt3\\
4\sin^2x&=\sqrt3+2\sin x-2\sqrt3\sin x\\
4\sin^2x-2\sin x+2\sqrt3\sin x-\sqrt3&=0\\
2\sin x(2\sin x-1)+\sqrt3(2\sin x-1)&=0\\
(2\sin x-1)(2\sin x+\sqrt3)&=0
\end{align}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: The good ol' factoring by grouping does the trick here, and is a very useful technique when solving quadratic equations in trig ratios.

Comment: thank you! Have a great day

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Simplify your solutions with $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt3} = 1+\sqrt3$. Therefore $\sin x= \frac12,\> -\frac{\sqrt3}2$.